Intercept estimates VERY different comparing glm and glmm
Can anyone explain the following puzzling phenomenon?  I'm fitting a binomial glmm using glmer from the lme4 package of R. The mean of the binary response variable in the dataset is about 0.1.  When I fit an intercept-only glmm with the necessary random effects, I get a estimate of the intercept that makes little sense:
> history.glmer.c.9 <- glmer(contaminated ~ (1|ID), family = binomial, data = inspected)
> summary(history.glmer.c.9)  
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: contaminated ~ (1 | ID)
   Data: inspected

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 32730.4  32748.5 -16363.2  32726.4    64539 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.2088 -0.0049 -0.0049 -0.0049  4.1520 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID.         (Intercept) 591.6    24.32   
Number of obs: 64541, groups:  ID, 51445

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -10.60404    0.07398  -143.3   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

I think that this estimate of the intercept is too low - I was expecting something around -2, which is what I get from the intercept-only glm.
> history.glm.c.9 <- glm(contaminated ~ 1, family = binomial, data = inspected)
> summary(history.glm.c.9)  

Call:
glm(formula = contaminated ~ 1, family = binomial, data = inspected)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.87428    0.01159  -161.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 50618  on 64540  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 50618  on 64540  degrees of freedom
AIC: 50620

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

Noteworthy comments

AIC suggests that the glmm is a much better fit than the glm (32730
cf 50620).
I get the same intercept estimate using glmmTMB, so I don't think it's just glmer.
The group membership is highly skewed (see following table); the vast majority of the groups are singletons.
The ICC is very high but the singleton contamination rate (i.e., the
rate for single-unit groups) is about the same as the contamination
rate for the larger groups.
The failure rate at the group level is about 0.1 as well.

> table(table(inspected$ID))

     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14 
582847  35629   7137   3268   1609    828    492    296    195     99     66     72     20     13 
    15     16     17     19     25     26 
     6      5      8      2      1      1 

Thanks for any insights!

It's harder to interpret the GLMM intercept when the variance components are huge as they are here.  Remember that the intercept is a conditional parameter, not a marginal parameter. The marginal mean can be very different.
Here's a simple example using numbers like your output where the intercept is -10 but the marginal mean is 0.35 because the random intercept standard deviation is 24.
> expit<-function(eta) exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))
> expit(-10)
[1] 4.539787e-05
> mean(expit(-10+rnorm(1000,0,24)))
[1] 0.3489417


Thanks, Thomas, that makes sense.  Do you have any recommendations about extracting fixed-effects predictions in a case like this? I only retain the random effects to get better model selection and interval estimates.  I'm tempted to identify the model structure using glmm (to get the model selection broadly right) and then use the glm fixed effects and glmm SEs.  It's a hack but I can check its sins using simulation. Is that crazy?

NB: mean(expit(ranef(history.glmm.c.8)$cond[[1]]$`(Intercept)` - 10.6)) returns 0.13 so you're bang on ...

I don't know. I would typically fit marginal models and go with sandwich variances and perhaps GEE. You could also just compute marginal means and marginal constrasts from the fitted GLMM
